# Как сохранить число в нужной локали

Tags: java, swing

```
void setChance(double chance){
    lblChance.setText(String.format("%.2f", chance));
}

}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44931/discussion-on-question-by-s-oleg-------).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> В разных странах некоторые записи принято производить по-разному. Например, в одних странах дробное число принято писать с точкой «3.68», а в других с запятой «3,68».  Java нам позволяет соблюдать эти традиции.

(с) [источник](http://study-java.ru/uroki-java/formatirovanie-chisel-i-texta-v-java/)

В Вашем случае:

Если нужна точка:

```
String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", 12.3456) // 12.35
```

Если нужна запятая:

```
String.format(Locale.FRANCE, "%.2f", 12.3456) // 12,35
```